# Linked List error: "MaxFormatDepthExceeded"

Tags: list-manipulation

On my Mathematica 11,

```
Fold[{#2, #1} &, {}, Range[400]]
```

will give

[image]

What is this?

And

```
Fold[{#2, #1} &, {}, Range[5000]]
```

will give

> $RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 4096 exceeded during
>   evaluation of MakeBoxes[909,StandardForm].

What is wrong?

Comment: This is basically a stack-overflow-error ;) . The default $RecursionLimit is not that big. The recursion limit during formatting seems even smaller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are just formatting issues; running

```
a = Fold[{#2, #1} &, {}, Range[400]];
a[[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
```

illustrates this.

You can use `ToString` if you have to print it.

```
nlist = Fold[{#2, #1} &, {}, Range[400]];
```

To store the list for operation, and

```
ToString[nlist]
```

to call it.

Fortunately, the iteration error you get for `Range[5000]` just acts as a warning.
Just use `ToString[]` to see the whole thing, in the mean time, you can operate on the array just fine.

Comment: Ok, so it is just frontend limit, right? I found that if run in WolframKernel, there is no such problem.

Comment: @matheorem I assume so, yes. Unfortunately that makes it less likely to be patched, as it is probably designed behaviour.